# First time using github and want to know command to access a repository

Tags: github

I just installed github in ubuntu and i don't know the commands to login with my username and password and command to access a repository and work on it
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Best way for linux is probably to give github your public key in your settings page, rather than log in as such.  Then you can add a github repository to your local repository with `git remote add git@github.com:<repopath>` and push/pull from it with `git push` and `git pull` respectively using SSH for authentication instead of username and password.

If you don't understand any of what I've just said, I'd recommend looking at some tutorials, like [this GitHub help article](https://help.github.com/articles/create-a-repo) or [Try Git](http://try.github.io/levels/1/challenges/1).